# Mask last three bits in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy 2D array with the following unique values:

```
[ 64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79 128 129
 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 192 193 194 195 196
 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 255]
```

I want to mask those values in the numpy 2D array, where **ANY** of the last 3 bits of the value are 1. I am doing this, but not sure if it is correct or indeed the best way to achieve it:

```
mask = ((arr & 3) == 0)
```

Comment: Yes, it seems fine. Is that the extent of your question?

Comment: @coldspeed, yes.

Comment: If you want to mask the last 3 bit shouldn't you do the & with 7?

Comment: By "mask" you mean you want to select those elements? Then you should compare for `>= 0`. Or if all of them should be `1` then compare `== 7`.

Comment: @Crivella and a_guest, I am looking for the case when ANY of the last 3 bits are 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by:

> mask those values in the numpy 2D array, where **ANY** of the last 3 bits of the value are 1

you mean "**select** those elements in which any of the three least significant bits are nonzero", you could do:

```
mask = np.bitwise_and(arr, 0b111) > 0
```

Arguably, using the function [`numpy.bitwise_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html) instead of the `&` operator makes the code more readable.

#### Sample run

```
In [35]: arr = np.arange(17)

In [36]: arr
Out[36]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])

In [37]: mask = np.bitwise_and(arr, 0b111) > 0

In [38]: mask
Out[38]: 
array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False])

In [39]: for x in arr[mask]:
    ...:     b = bin(x)
    ...:     print('{}{:0>5}'.format(b[:2], b[2:]))
    ...: 
    ...: 
0b00001
0b00010
0b00011
0b00100
0b00101
0b00110
0b00111
0b01001
0b01010
0b01011
0b01100
0b01101
0b01110
0b01111
```

Comment: I am looking for the case when ANY of the last 3 bits are 1. Your solution only works if ALL of the last 3 bits are 1

Comment: This code is correct? For example, selecting 0b10101 (21), applying the code above np.bitwise_and(21,np.bitwise_not(np.bitwise_and(21,0b111)) gives us 16 which is 0b10000.

Comment: I have had misunderstood at first the meaning of **mask**. The OP has made this point clear now and I've edited my answer accordingly